# ImageView fica branco ao carregar Activity e preto ao receber imagem da galeria

Tags: android, imageview, uri

Eu estou salvando os usuários com uma imagem padrão no momento em que se cadastram no aplicativo e essa imagem é um drawable que é salvo como uma String no banco de dados:

Método da classe Controller:

```
public static boolean cadastraUsuario(Context context, String nome, String email, String senha) throws JSONException, IOException {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.avatar);

        SocialMarketDB db = new SocialMarketDB(context);

        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(nome, email, senha, bitmap);
        return db.cadastraUsuario(usuario);
    }
```

Método que salva os dados no SQLite:

```
public boolean cadastraUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        boolean resp = false;
        String id = usuario.getId();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("id", usuario.getId());
            values.put("nome", usuario.getNome());
            values.put("url_foto", Util.converteBitmapString(usuario.getFoto()));
            values.put("senha", usuario.getSenha());

            Cursor cursor = db.query("usuario", null, "id=?", new String[]{id}, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                db.insert("usuario", "", values);
                resp = true;
            }
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

Util.converteBitmapString:

```
public static String converteBitmapString(Bitmap imagemBitmap) {
        final int COMPRESSION_QUALITY = 100;
        String stringImagem;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayBitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imagemBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, COMPRESSION_QUALITY,
                byteArrayBitmapStream);
        byte[] b = byteArrayBitmapStream.toByteArray();
        stringImagem = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return stringImagem;
    }
```

Activity:

```
btncadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {  
            if(Controller.cadastraUsuario(ActivityCriarConta.this,nome,email,senha1)) {
                                Util.alert(getResources().getString(R.string.alert_cadastro_sucesso), ActivityCriarConta.this);
                }
            }
}
```

Quando entro na Activity para editar perfil, o ImageView que deveria ter o drawable que eu salvei fica em branco:

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_editar_perfil);

            Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
            if( args !=null) {
                emailUsuario = args.getString("id");
            }

            Usuario usuario = Controller.buscaUsuario(this,id);
            imgperfil = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagemPerfil);
            imgperfil.setImageBitmap(usuario.getFoto());
    }
```

E quando escolho uma nova imagem da galeria, o ImageView fica preto:

```
 alterarimg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    carregarGaleria();
                }
            });
    public void carregarGaleria() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
           //Verifica se tem permissão, se tiver chama o método escolheImagem()
        }

        //onRequestPermissionsResult...

        public void escolheImagem(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            InputStream stream = null;
            if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        bitmap.recycle();
                    }
                    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                    imgperfil.setImageURI(imageUri);
                } finally {
                    if (stream != null)
                        try {
                            stream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }

            }
        }

    public String getImagePath(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] campos = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, campos, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();
        return path;
    }
```

Peço desculpas por postar um código tão extenso, mas é que o meu erro pode estar em qualquer uma dessas partes e eu não estou conseguindo identificar qual.
A parte de escolher imagem da galeria estava funcionando normalmente, não lembro de ter mexido em alguma coisa que possa estar fazendo esse erro acontecer.

Comment: Não deu pra entender qual é o problema, a imagem está ficando em preto e branco quando vc coloca em uma ImageView, é isso?

Comment: Quando carrego a Activty ela fica branca e quando escolho uma imagem da galeria ela fica preta. Vou mudar o titulo da pergunta

Comment: Primeiramente, o drawable é um int. É um valor numérico. Em segundo lugar, é muito mais fácil gerenciar imagens com uma biblioteca chamada Glide: https://github.com/bumptech/glide.
É só usar a imagem assim: Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.img1).into(imgView);